# Adding a prefix in an array within an array and then returning it

Tags: php, arrays

This is what I have:

```
 $tests = array(
    'id' => 'world',
    'level2' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'world2'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'world3'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'world4'
        ),
    )
);
```

What I want - Prefix something like `'hello '` to all `'id'`s in `'level2'` array

What I've tried:

```
$tests = testing( $tests );

function testing( $tests ) {
    foreach ( $tests['level2'] as $test ) {
        $test['id'] = 'hello ' . $test['id'];
    }

    return $tests;
}

var_dump( $tests );
```

Results: `array(2) { ["id"]=> string(5) "world" ["level2"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(6) "world2" } [1]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(6) "world3" } [2]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(6) "world4" } } }`

The problem - Doesn't work.

Anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the key to change your original array:

```
$tests = testing( $tests );

function testing( $tests ) {
    foreach ( $tests['level2'] as $key=>$test ) {
        $tests['level2'][$key]['id'] = 'hello ' . $test['id'];
    }

    return $tests;
}

var_dump( $tests );
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers: PHP offers via [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/array_map) a function so you don't need to use any loops at all.

```
function addToId($level) {
    $level['id'] = 'hello'.$level['id'];
    return $level;
}
function testing($tests) {
    $tests['level'] = array_map('addToId', $tests['level']);
    return $tests;
}
```

Here you only need to make sure, you call `array_map()` on `$tests['level']` and not `$tests` itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's something new to me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when using the `foreach` loop, `$test` becomes a copy, so updating that won't update the original Array.

You may fix that by passing $test as a reference:

```
function testing( $tests ) {
    foreach ( $tests['level2'] as &$test ) {
        $test['id'] = 'hello ' . $test['id'];
    }

    return $tests;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, isn't that code block exactly the same as mine?

Comment: Almost, it is passing `$test` as a reference, by using **`&$test`** instead. Which fixes your problem in a more compact way.